# Prevent HTML table to use full page width in Quarto

Tags: html, layout, quarto

I would like to use HTML tables in Quarto, but I would like to prevent it using the full page width. Here is a reproducible example:

```
---
title: "HTML tables in Quarto"
format: html
---

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 1

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 2 {tbl-colwidths="[75,25]"}
```

Output:

[image]

As we can see, table 1 is normal and you can see it takes the full page width. Table 2 has `tbl-colwdiths` options, but this doesn't make the table smaller in width and is also the full page width. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to prevent the HTML table to use the full page width in `Quarto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option to use `.columns` div to get column layout

````
---
title: "HTML tables in Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---


:::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="70%"}

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 1

:::
::::


```{css, echo=FALSE}
.center-table table {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

::: {.center-table}

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 2

:::
````

---

[image]

Comment: Hi @shafee, Do you know how to center the second table? Thanks!

Comment: @Quinten, just want to add, [Bootstrap's css grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/) (answered by @Julian) is better option actually, for creating both simple and complex layouts. If you go through the link attached with this comment, you will understand what I am saying.

Comment: The centering part is, however, not very elegant for the css grid's in my opinion (see my edit). It does the trick but involves two empty colums of equal size.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use the [css grid system](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/page-layout.html#css-grid):

```
---
title: "HTML tables in Quarto"
format: html
---

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 1

::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-7}

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 2 

:::
:::
```

[image]

Edit: If you want to center, you could utilize the default of twelve columns in the css grid, e.g.

```
::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-2}
:::


::: {.g-col-8}

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Table 2 

:::

::: {.g-col-2}
:::

:::
```